# Не работают одновременно установленные якоря для Shapes в AnchorPane JavaFX

Tags: javafx, layout

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, при установке одновременно двух якорей bottomAnchor и topAnchor обычный элемент, такой как кнопка ведет себя предсказуемо, т.е. при изменении высоты AnchorPane растягивается вертикально. А, скажем Rectangle, вообще не меняет своих размеров. При этом отдельно установленные якоря работают одинаково. Кто может объяснить, почему так?[image: До растягивания][image: После растягивания]

Comment: Полагаю это может быть связано с тем, что у фигур другая цепочка наследования к Node, и где-то упущена обработка этих свойств.

Comment: Я тоже пришел к такому выводу. Хотелось бы понять, это баг или фича? Можно ли это как-то вправить или придется вручную обрабатывать изменения размеров AnchorPane'а

Comment: Я бы обернул фигуру в pane, vbox, и пр, для него свойства Anchor уже будут работать, а у фигуры сделал bind размеров к тому что обернуто.

Comment: Идея шикарная. Вопрос такой, можно ли забиндить размеры из fxml?